# is there a way to define a Model in mongoose that does not have the .save() method?

Tags: validation, node.js, model, mongoose

what i'm trying to do is define a Student model with a field called "schedules" which contains an Array of Schedule instances, but i don't want the Schedule model to be able to saved to it's own collection.

Here's some code, it'll make more sense:

```
var ScheduleSchema = new Schema({
    day:    {type: Number, min: 0, max: 6},
    time:   {type: Number, min: 0, max:24}
});

var StudentSchema = new Schema({
    firstName:  String,
    schedule:   [ScheduleSchema]
});

var Schedule = mongoose.model("Schedule", ScheduleSchema);
var Student = mongoose.model(modelName, StudentSchema);
Student.Schedule = Schedule;
```

the problem i'm having with this bit of code is that when i do:

```
var schedule = new Student.Schedule({day: 3, time: 15});
```

i would get something like this, when i console.log

```
{ "day" : 3, "time" : 15, "_id" : ObjectId("5019f34924ee03e20900001a") }
```

i got around the auto generating of _id, by explicitly defining _id in the schema,

```
var ScheduleSchema = new Schema({
    _id:    ObjectIdSchema,
    day:    {type: Number, min: 0, max: 6},
    time:   {type: Number, min: 0, max:24}
});
```

now it' just gives me:

```
{ "day" : 3, "time" : 15}
```

that's probably a hack..and not something i want to rely on.

the other problem is that if i do

```
schedule.save()
```

it'll actually create a collection and save the document to the database.

is there a way to disable save() for Schedule? is there a correct way to do this?

i could probably stick with what i have, or settle for Mixed types but lose out on the validation..

Answer (score 0):

Why would you do `schedule.save()` anyway? You are supposed to save the parent object (i.e. `Student` object), not embedded document. If you save `schedule` then the `_id` will be appended by default. This won't happen if you save `Student` object with `schedule` as an embedded document.

Also there is no real reason for disabling `.save` method on your `Schedule` model (this is an interesting feature that allows you to have `Schedule` model as a model for embedded documents and a model for stand-alone documents at the same time). Just don't use it. Do something like this:

```
var student = new Student({ firstName: 'John' });
var schedule = new Schedule({ day: 3, time: 15 });
student.schedules.push( schedule );
student.save( );
```

Comment: of course i wouldn't do schedule.save() since i wrote this. i just didn't want ambiguous code being able to do things it's not supposed to. also you mentioned that the '_id' wont get generated if i did save on the student, but the only way i can get that behavior is by adding that '_id' hack i did in the ScheduleSchema.. unless that's not a hack, i just couldn't find it documented anywhere in their documentation.

Comment: Really? I can't test it at the moment, but I'll get back to you in few hours.

Comment: yeah, i wrote the tests in mocha. i only got the tests to pass by add _id:    ObjectIdSchema, to the ScheduleSchema. i'm using mongoose 2.7.0 btw.